# How can you assign a single track to multiple outputs on Cubase 5?

Tags: software, daw, cubase

Hello all I'm a drummer and I'm having a problem with cubase (noob),

I'm trying to setup my jamming studio.
**Equipment:**

- Laptop + USB Sound card interface (with 2 stereo outs or 4 mono)
- Amp
- Cubase 5
- 3x mixers

**Playback Tracks:**

1. Symphonic track
2. Guitars Track
3. Click Track

**Current Setup**

The drums are spread over 2 mixers and out to the 3rd.
Cubase on the laptop outputs through the sound interface.
The rest of the instruments like keyboards and lead guitar go through 3 3rd mixer.
The output goes to the Amp and My headphones.

**The Desired output**

Whilst jamming, we need the symphony & guitars (cubase tracks) and everything else except the click to come out the amp.
However in my headphones, I need the Symphony and the click only.

All I'm stuck with, is trying to output a single track to multiple outputs on cubase, I can isolate the click to my headphones through cubase, but I cannot play the symphony on the headphones because it outs to the Amp, I've tried some tricks I found online, but couldn't get it to work, and doubt that they will.

How can you assign a single track to multiple outputs on Cubase 5?

Comment: It's been a while since I used v5 - I'm currently testing 8... but investigate the Control Room options. Manual here if you don't have it - https://www.steinberg.net/en/support/downloads/downloads_cubase_5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screenshots are from Nuendo 4, the coeval of Cubase 5. So it should be similar.

In the "VST Connections" menu add two stereo busses for each stereo-out of your USB sound card. I called them "Main" and "Headphones".
[image: VST Connections]

On channel settings pick "Main" for Symphony and Guitar channel outs.

[image]

If your click is the default Cubase click, in the "VST Connections" menu, disable it for the "Main", and enable it for the "Headphone".
[image]

If your click is not the default Cubase click but an individual click track, pick "No Bus" for the Click channel out.

[image]

"Main" outs are set. Now we should set the sends for "Headphone".

Go to "Sends" of channel Symphony (and the Click track if there is one) and add "Headphone" to one of the sends.

[image]

By default, sends are added "disabled with volume fader minimized". Don't forget to both enable and increase the volume after adding a send. At the end it should look like this:

[image]

You can solo the tracks and use the main mixer to check visually if the channel routings work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is what's referred to as a "[bus track](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_audio_bus_track)" (though I've really only heard it called a "bus"). On the amp bus, you'll have everything (minus the click). On the headphones bus, you'll have the symphony and click (though you may need to render/bounce the click down to its own audio track. Offhand, I don't know how to route the click to a specific track/bus on its own.)

[Here is a link](https://www.steinberg.net/en/support/tips_and_tricks/archive_2012/cubase_6_multiple_outputs_february_2012.html) that explains how to set these up in Cubase 6. I think it's similar enough in Cubase 5 to figure it out from these steps. If not, let me know and I'll try to post an update with instructions specific to 5.

Comment: Thank you, I've attempted this for a couple of days and couldn't get it to work, I ended up duplicating the track